# how to get browsed file location by user when he wants to download a file

Tags: playframework-2.3

this is my html code to make user to download a file and it is hitting controller

```
window.location.href="@routes.ListManagementController.downloadList("+listName+")?listname="+listName;
```

this is my controller code:

```
String listName = Form.form().bindFromRequest().get("listname");
        response().setContentType("application/x-download"); 
        response().setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename="+listName+"_data_export.csv");
```

The above two `respose()` statements make a pop up to download a file I want the browsed file location

```
      File file = new File("C:/csv/" + filename);
```

So, using servlet api we can write the content into browsed file location using `respose.getOutputStream()` method. In play there are is no support for servlet. I want browsed file location selected by user so that i can give that location to `File` and write the file over there.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the location of a directory on the client, and even if you could, your server side could wouldn't be able to write to it (since it would usually be on a different computer).